# Can't set up a React-Redux boilerplate

Tags: reactjs, npm, redux, react-redux, npm-install

I am doing a project and had problem with my previous boilerplate, therefore I tried to use another one.
I've found [this one](https://github.com/mezod/boilerplate-koa-redux-react) on github that is very similar and seems to be basic.
I've cloned it and I runned npm install, but when I get to run the server I get this error message back and I have no idea on how to fix it.
It is very similar to the message I had with my previous boilerplate.

```
$ npm run webserver

> boilerplate-koa-redux-react@1.0.0 webserver C:\Users\qwepo\Desktop\RRWeather
> node api/src/server.js

events.js:141
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: listen EADDRINUSE :::3000
    at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:907:11)
    at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:930:20)
    at Server._listen2 (net.js:1250:14)
    at listen (net.js:1286:10)
    at Server.listen (net.js:1382:5)
    at Application.app.listen (C:\Users\qwepo\Desktop\RRWeather\node_modules\koa\lib\application.js:74:24)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\qwepo\Desktop\RRWeather\api\src\server.js:8:5)
    at Module._compile (module.js:409:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:343:32)

npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.15063
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "run" "webserver"
npm ERR! node v4.6.0
npm ERR! npm  v2.15.9
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! boilerplate-koa-redux-react@1.0.0 webserver: `node api/src/server.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the boilerplate-koa-redux-react@1.0.0 webserver script 'node api/src/server.js'.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the boilerplate-koa-redux-react package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node api/src/server.js
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs boilerplate-koa-redux-react
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!
npm ERR!     npm owner ls boilerplate-koa-redux-react
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\qwepo\Desktop\RRWeather\npm-debug.log
```

This is the npm-debug.log file

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ 'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'run',
1 verbose cli   'webserver' ]
2 info using npm@2.15.9
3 info using node@v4.6.0
4 verbose run-script [ 'prewebserver', 'webserver', 'postwebserver' ]
5 info prewebserver boilerplate-koa-redux-react@1.0.0
6 info webserver boilerplate-koa-redux-react@1.0.0
7 verbose unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 info boilerplate-koa-redux-react@1.0.0 Failed to exec webserver script
9 verbose stack Error: boilerplate-koa-redux-react@1.0.0 webserver: `node api/src/server.js`
9 verbose stack Exit status 1
9 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\lifecycle.js:217:16)
9 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)
9 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:172:7)
9 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\spawn.js:24:14)
9 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)
9 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:172:7)
9 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:829:16)
9 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:211:5)
10 verbose pkgid boilerplate-koa-redux-react@1.0.0
11 verbose cwd C:\Users\qwepo\Desktop\RRWeather
12 error Windows_NT 10.0.15063
13 error argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "run" "webserver"
14 error node v4.6.0
15 error npm  v2.15.9
16 error code ELIFECYCLE
17 error boilerplate-koa-redux-react@1.0.0 webserver: `node api/src/server.js`
17 error Exit status 1
18 error Failed at the boilerplate-koa-redux-react@1.0.0 webserver script 'node api/src/server.js'.
18 error This is most likely a problem with the boilerplate-koa-redux-react package,
18 error not with npm itself.
18 error Tell the author that this fails on your system:
18 error     node api/src/server.js
18 error You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
18 error     npm bugs boilerplate-koa-redux-react
18 error Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
18 error
18 error     npm owner ls boilerplate-koa-redux-react
18 error There is likely additional logging output above.
19 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

How can I fix this, and why I got this problem?

Comment: the port 3000 is already in use, make sure to either stop whatever you are running on this port if its some of your application or else change the port where the redux boilerplate starts

Comment: Here's the clue `Error: listen EADDRINUSE :::3000`

Comment: Changing port to anyone else gives an error code ELIFECYCLE.

Answer (score 0):

`Error: listen EADDRINUSE :::3000` something is already running on that port. Check what it is and kill process. I'm not using windows but there are a lot of [solutions in google](https://rodrigothescientist.wordpress.com/2013/07/23/kills-the-process-at-a-certain-port-in-windows-7/).

Comment: I am on W10 and it appears that the process is not found.